# How can I seed srand with time() and a key(string)

Tags: c++, time, key, seed, srand

Let's say I have this key

```
string key = "WID%ij38(@$151#3da=="
```

How can I seed using `srand()` in C++ together with `time()` and the key?

It is not possible to do `srand(time(NULL)*key))` because key is a string.

Anyway to convert it?

Comment: You can try string length of `key`.

Answer (score 2):

You could try hashing the string

`srand(std::hash<std::string>{}(key));`

Comment: Well, the question asks for that to be combined with `time(NULL)` - an XOR would be the best bet there.  +1 for a good solution to the trickier bit.  It's noteworthy that some `std::hash<std::string>` implementations are pretty weak - for example, last I looked Visual C++'s library only incorporated 10 characters spaced along the string (to give predictable and fast performance for long strings, but at a potentially significant cost to collisions).  A cryptographic hash will be far more random.

Answer (score 2):

Not strictly so, [the argument to `srand` must be an `unsigned int`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f0d4wb4t.aspx). Now, you could take your character string and create a hash of it that gives you an `unsigined int`, and work from that.

Of course, if you're trying to increase entropy, for security reasons, you may well be disappointed, especially if the string is fixed or comes from the user in any way.